# python - optimizing branching logic

Tags: python

I currently have a kind of nasty block of code I'm writing for a program that simulates the growth of crab (exciting stuff.....).  This program later gets absorbed by a larger simulation, so speed of code matters.  One of my slowest blocks of code contains this nasty branching logic.  I was hoping someone could think of a way to make this more efficient....

For context, this block of code is basically saying:  "Am I regenerating a claw?  If so which one.  If the left/right claw is regrowing, is it the dominant or non-dominant hand? Given this, apply this number xyz"

```
if left_or_right_growing == 'left':
    if crab.rightclawCrusher == True:
        crab.rightclaw_size = new_crushersize
        if crab.moltnumber_for_claw_removal_left < crab.numberofmolts: #so it doesn't overwrite budding claw growth
            crab.leftclaw_size = max(new_pincersize * crab.proportion_of_new_claw_thats_grownback()+adj, crab.leftclaw_size)
    elif crab.rightclawCrusher == False:
        crab.rightclaw_size = new_pincersize + adj
        if crab.moltnumber_for_claw_removal_left < crab.numberofmolts: #so it doesn't overwrite budding claw growth
            crab.leftclaw_size = max(new_crushersize * crab.proportion_of_new_claw_thats_grownback(), crab.leftclaw_size)

elif left_or_right_growing == 'right':
    if crab.rightclawCrusher == True:
        crab.leftclaw_size = new_pincersize + adj
        if crab.moltnumber_for_claw_removal_right < crab.numberofmolts: #so it doesn't overwrite budding claw growth
            crab.rightclaw_size = max(new_crushersize  * crab.proportion_of_new_claw_thats_grownback(), crab.rightclaw_size)
    elif crab.rightclawCrusher == False:
        crab.leftclaw_size = new_crushersize
        if crab.moltnumber_for_claw_removal_right < crab.numberofmolts: #so it doesn't overwrite budding claw growth
            crab.rightclaw_size = max(new_pincersize  * crab.proportion_of_new_claw_thats_grownback() +adj, crab.rightclaw_size)

elif left_or_right_growing == 'both':
    pro_left, pro_right = crab.proportion_of_new_claw_thats_grownback()
    if pro_left > 1. or pro_right > 1.:
        print('ERROR IN TRANFORM:  pro_left: ' + str(pro_left) +'   pro_right:  ' + str(pro_right))
    if crab.rightclawCrusher == True:
        if crab.moltnumber_for_claw_removal_left < crab.numberofmolts: #so it doesn't overwrite budding claw growth
            crab.leftclaw_size = max(new_pincersize * pro_left+ adj, crab.leftclaw_size) 

        if crab.moltnumber_for_claw_removal_right < crab.numberofmolts:
            crab.rightclaw_size = max(new_crushersize  * pro_right, crab.rightclaw_size)                    

    else:  
        if crab.moltnumber_for_claw_removal_right < crab.numberofmolts: #so it doesn't overwrite budding claw growth
            crab.rightclaw_size = max(new_pincersize  * pro_right+ adj, crab.rightclaw_size)

        if crab.moltnumber_for_claw_removal_left < crab.numberofmolts:    
            crab.leftclaw_size = max(new_crushersize * pro_left, crab.leftclaw_size)
```

Comment: Change `elif <whatever> == False:` to just `else:` if the only possibilities are `True` and `False`.

Comment: Is there some way you can cache the result of all the tests so you don't have to repeat them every time?

Comment: Unfort they're dynamic and change periodically (ie, unlike a human where I'm always going to be right handed)

Comment: Obviously it wouldn't be the same all the time, but if you can cache the result of a decision tree in a data structure, using the functional style in Dmitry's answer, that saves lots of jumping around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working off what the previous person said you could create a function for all the nested if statements that appear after the three of your conditions. Then you would place them in a dictionary and call on them as such. Here is an example illustrating this method:

```
def fizz(x, y):
    return x*y

def foo(k, v):
    return k - v

def buzz(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Then you make a dictionary as such:

```
opts = {'left':fizz, 'right':foo, 'both':buzz}
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
if left_or_right_growing == 'left':
    opts['left'](1,2)
    ## output is 2

elif left_or_right_growing == 'right':
    opts['right'](3,4)
    ## output is -1

elif left_or_right_growing == 'both':
    opts['both'](5,6)
    ## output is 11
```

And to answer the question you posed to the other person, yes, this method should end up being faster than a bunch of nested if statements. Benchmark it on your code and see what happens.

Edit: Some sample benchmarks using my method:

```
real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.007s
```

And then when I use your method and replace the functions with an if loop of it's own:

```
real    0m0.037s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.009s
```

Here is the script I use to test the function method:

```
import sys

def fizz(crab, x, y):
    if crab == 2:
        print 'Hello'
    else:
        return x*y

def foo(crab, k, v):
    if crab == 2:
        print 'Hello'
    else:
        return k - v

def buzz(crab, a, b):
    if crab == 2:
        print 'Hello'
    else:
        return a + b


opts = {'left':fizz, 'right':foo, 'both':buzz}

def main():
    left_or_right_growing = sys.argv[1]
    crab = int(sys.argv[2])
    if left_or_right_growing == 'left':
        opts['left'](crab,1,2)

    elif left_or_right_growing == 'right':
        opts['right'](crab,3,4)

    elif left_or_right_growing == 'both':
        opts['both'](crab,5,6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To test the if loops I just replace the functions with one simple `if` loop. As you can see even for a simple task like this the function method is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this block of code in a function to make it look cleaner:

```
if crab.rightclawCrusher == True:
            crab.rightclaw_size = new_crushersize
            if crab.moltnumber_for_claw_removal_left < crab.numberofmolts: #so it doesn't overwrite budding claw growth
                crab.leftclaw_size = max(new_pincersize * crab.proportion_of_new_claw_thats_grownback()+adj, crab.leftclaw_size)
        elif crab.rightclawCrusher == False:
            crab.rightclaw_size = new_pincersize + adj
            if crab.moltnumber_for_claw_removal_left < crab.numberofmolts: #so it doesn't overwrite budding claw growth
                crab.leftclaw_size = max(new_crushersize * crab.proportion_of_new_claw_thats_grownback(), crab.leftclaw_size)
```

Comment: @keynesiancross it will not make it any faster, the way I see it there isn't much you can to do make it faster, unless if you turned your string comparisons to enums of some sort